# My USB shows different sizes

Tags: usb-flash-drive, mount

I have a 64GB USB Flash Disk ([link](http://www.maplin.co.uk/64gb-usb-flash-drive-635953) - Maplin, Intenso Rainbow Line) but when I put it into my computer (Ubuntu LiveCD) it reports that, out of 63.3GB, 60GB has been used, yet the files only total 27.8GB. How can this be?

It doesn't seem counterfeit, as I bought it from a Maplin Store, which I trust. I've had the stick for about a year, so am unable to take it back.

Notes: It is FAT32 Formatted (despite what Ubuntu thinks), could this be the cause?

[image: What I see]

Here's the same in Windows (with hidden files on):
[image]

Comment: There is clearly a hidden file that is taking up your space.  Can you post the output of a command that lists the size, filename, and date of every file on the device?

Comment: @Ramhound How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for a easy solution. Copy all visible file to laptop/desktop then format the USB Drive and again copy/paste the same in the USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly have a hidden file which is taking up space, a corrupted MFT, or, if you have a large number of small files, the cluster size is causing them to take up much more space than a single, larger file of the same size. Also, if you use it on multiple operating systems, there can be "attributes" files that are hidden. To be sure, I would list all the files and attributes out.

Comment: Surely opening the properties of the USB's mounted folder (as you can see above, showing both 60GB (pie chart) and 27GB (third row) used)

Comment: Seeing the "size on disk" from Windows makes me think that it could be a corrupt FAT. If possible, you could try copying the files to another drive, format the drive, and copy them back to see if it does the same thing. Also, if you have too many files in the root directory it can show some weird things, but I think that may only be in Windows that it gets weird.

Comment: Should I reformat using the LiveCD? Using the Windows Computer Management (Right-Click My Computer > Manage) it only lets me format the Drive as NTFS if I format the whole disk. I have to go for about half the drive (maybe slightly more - I'm not sure) to get access to FAT32.

Comment: Also note that the sizes are different because Windows thinks that GB and GiB are the same. When viewing in GParted, I see the same sizes as I do on Windows, and when unmounted I see the sizes that appear for all files in Windows.

Comment: I have had luck using NTFS volumes (as flash drives) on both Linux and Windows, but your mileage may vary. I have never had a flash drive that is larger than 16 GB, so I have not run across this issue. You can try reformatting it from the LiveCD as a test.